# Reaktor tutorials/book recommendations?

Tags: tutorial, reaktor

I've just bought reaktor and i'm looking for some tutorials to get started, can anyone recommend some videos or a book? I don't mind paying for one of the online video tutorials around but i wanted to see if anyone could recommend a decent one, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are some good basics on youtube if I remember correctly.

The big thing really is remembering there are two types of data, numbers and audio stream. If you want to use audio to say... change the frequency of a filter you have to put a converter between the two.

Other than that if you know the principles of cv and gate (cv being pitch, gate being on.off) then you should be partially set.

Have a look on youtube on how to create a subtractive synth in reaktor. This is part 1 of what looks like a decent series:

Answer (score 3):

I have been slowly delving into reaktor over the past year or so and I am finding a ton of great resources here. [adsrsounds.com](http://adsrsounds.com/)

Also, I am reading [Designing Sound](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/designing-sound) by Andy Farnell.  It is using Pure Data, but a lot of the same principles apply.

Good Luck!